# Easiest Way To Center One Item and Align Another One to the Right

Tags: html, css

I have a container with two elements. I want one of them to be centered horizontally, while the other one is aligned right / pushed to the right side of the container.

I tried using FlexBox and setting `margin: auto;` for the element that's supposed to be centered, but that makes its left and right margins exactly equal, which means it's not perfectly centerd due to the second element taking up some space (see snippet).

```css
#container {
  display: flex;
  width: 250px;
  background-color: #2c3e50;
}

#element-1, #element-2 {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #16a085;
}

#element-1 {
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="element-1"></div>
  <div id="element-2"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: You could hack a solution by making the second element absolutely positioned on the right.

Answer (score 0):

this way ?

```css
#container {
  width      : 250px;
  height     : 50px;
  background : darkblue;
  position   : relative;
  }
#element-1,
#element-2 {
  width      : 50px;
  height     : 50px;
  background : darkgreen;
  position   : absolute;
  top        : 0;
  }
#element-1 {
  right     : 50%;
  transform : translate(50%, 0);
  }
#element-2 {
  right     : 0;
  }
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="element-1"></div>
  <div id="element-2"></div>
</div>
```